# How to get signed transaction hash before mining? [Ethereum]

Tags: raw-transaction, hash

Is it possible to get transaction hash before send transaction to node? How  transactionHash is calculated?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction hash is the rlp hash of the signed transaction: i.e.

https://medium.com/@codetractio/inside-an-ethereum-transaction-fa94ffca912f
[image: example]

Comment: Is it the same hash as received by ETHEREUMJS-TX.hash()? [ethereumjs.Util.sha3(ethereumjs.RLP.encode(tx_.raw)).toString('hex')]

Comment: I believe this is wrong: the transaction is hashed, THEN signed. [From the linked article](https://miro.medium.com/max/1142/1*4Ta0bUfCEmgH4kOrNl8mKg.png)